# How can I fill a tikzpicture "fill" with a pattern?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill, pattern, venn-diagrams

I'm using the following to generate a Venn diagram, per the example [here](http://latex-cookbook.net/articles/venn-diagram/):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[blend group=soft light]
      \fill[blue!30!white]  (135:1.2) circle (2);
      \fill[red!30!white]   ( 45:1.2) circle (2);
      \fill[gray!30!white]  (-90:1.2) circle (2);
    \end{scope}
    \node at (135:2)  {1};
    \node at ( 45:2)  {2};
    \node at (-90:2)  {3};
    \node             {6};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

However, instead of blue, red and gray I would like to use pattern fills like crosshatch or dots, per the [tikzpgf manual](https://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf), page 217. When I try swapping the name of the color in the fill with the name of the pattern, the diagram no longer compiles. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patterns work.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[blend group=soft light]
      \fill[pattern=north east lines]  (135:1.2) circle[radius=2];
      \fill[pattern=north west lines]   ( 45:1.2) circle[radius=2];
      \fill[pattern=crosshatch]  (-90:1.2) circle[radius=2];
    \end{scope}
    \node at (135:2)  {1};
    \node at ( 45:2)  {2};
    \node at (-90:2)  {3};
    \node             {6};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You may want to switch to `patterns.meta`, though.

Comment: Yep, this works! How do I switches to `patterns.meta`? I tried `\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}`, but that didn't work. I'm using Debian.

Comment: @laskdfjiweioeiecoin The library was added a bit more than a year ago to CTAN, so you may have an older installation which you need to update.